# HTML5, positioning validation error messages

Tags: jquery, html

If I have a form and I use the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].oninvalid = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity("This field cannot be left blank");
            }
        };
        elements[i].oninput = function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        };
    }
});
```

How to put error message to correct position like in the image:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIj5V.gif]

Comment: Notice that that error is caused by your browser. (Google Chrome right?)

Comment: Yes, Chrome is the browser.

Comment: Make sure that the parent element (to which error box is being attached) has `position:relative;` style

Comment: If you are still interested in a fix for this, I can help. If so please add another comment, but don't for get to include "@joshuawilson" so that I will get notified. If you don't respond I will assume you moved on.

Comment: @joshuawilson, if you have something to contribute about this, just put it in here, you'll be helping not only to the person who made the question, but also you'll help any other who had a similar problem. Don't hold it back, share your thoughts.

Comment: i am also facing the similar problem... :(